# Expo React Native app with React Navigation 5, crashes on Android when touching initial screen from Navigator

Tags: android, react-native, crash, expo, react-navigation-v5

Problem: 
On android, I open the app and reach the navigator's initial screen, then touch it and it crashes completely (doesn't show errors).

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.6",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/tabs": "0.0.0-alpha.12",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.5.1",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.8",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.11",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.10",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.16",
    "apollo-link-state": "^0.4.2",
    "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.17",
    "aws-amplify": "^2.2.2",
    "aws-amplify-react": "^3.1.6",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^3.2.0",
    "aws-appsync": "^3.0.2",
    "aws-appsync-react": "^3.0.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.610.0",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "expo-font": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^8.0.2",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moments": "0.0.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "npm": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-clear-app-cache": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-image-grid": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-thumbnail-grid": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-ratings-declarative": "^3.4.1",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "yarn": "^1.21.1"
    },
```

app.json:

```
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "caballos-app",
        "description": "This project is really great.",
        "slug": "caballos-app",
        "privacy": "public",
        "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
        "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "updates": {
            "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": [
            "**/*"
        ],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true
        },
        "packagerOpts": { 
            "config": "metro.config.js", 
            "sourceExts": ["js","jsx","svg","ts","tsx"] 
        }
    }
}
```

metro.config.js:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

adb logcat:

```
02-27 17:38:58.521 32756 32756 E InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
02-27 17:38:58.522 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already prepared or hasn't been reset
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandler.prepare(GestureHandler.java:7)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.recordHandlerIfNotPresent(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:8)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.recordViewHandlersForPointer(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:5)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:12)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:5)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.onTouchEvent(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:4)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootHelper.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerRootHelper.java:2)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootView.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerRootView.java:1)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView.java:2)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:613)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1933)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4127)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at b.a.o.i.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:1)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:559)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13763)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5614)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5058)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5111)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5077)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5234)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5085)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5291)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5058)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5111)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5077)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5085)
02-27 17:38:58.523 32756 32756 E MessageQueue-JNI:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5058)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime: Process: host.exp.exponent, PID: 32756
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already prepared or hasn't been reset
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandler.prepare(GestureHandler.java:7)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.recordHandlerIfNotPresent(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:8)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.recordViewHandlersForPointer(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:5)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:12)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:5)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.onTouchEvent(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:4)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootHelper.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerRootHelper.java:2)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootView.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerRootView.java:1)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at abi36_0_0.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView.java:2)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3073)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:613)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1933)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4127)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at b.a.o.i.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:1)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:559)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13763)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5614)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5058)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5111)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5077)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5234)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5085)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5291)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5058)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5111)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5077)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5085)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5058)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7949)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7900)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7854)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8139)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:233)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:363)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8147)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
02-27 17:38:58.527 32756 32756 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Navigator:

```
import React from "react";
import SignUp from "./SignUp/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./SignIn"
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthRouter = () => {

    return(
        <Stack.Navigator>
             <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} options={{ title: 'Ingresar' }} />
             <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} options={{ title: 'Registro' }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}


export default AuthRouter;
```

App.js:

```
if(loading) return <Loading/>
else return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AuthRouter/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </ApolloProvider>
)
```

(I simplified some things that weren't important for the problem)

I know it's the Navigator as I tried with single screens and it doesn't crash.
I already dived every issue related. Checked the react navigation 5 troubleshooting too.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Post your stack trace for the crash (`adb logcat`) and post your `app.json`/`metro.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

The crash is because of overriding `sourceExts`. Remove these lines from your `app.json` and `metro.config.js`:

```
"sourceExts": ["js","jsx","svg","ts","tsx"]
```

See https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6919 for more details.

Comment: Thanks man! I removed it from app.json only and now it doesn't crash. Now my .svg imports don't work though, but I prefer to have that problem.

Comment: Hey @satya164! Do you know any workaround for the svg files problem? The docs say the line you suggested me to remove is required for them to function:

https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer#for-expo-sdk-v3000-or-older

Comment: Please check the issue I linked.

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6919#issuecomment-592093015 this one did the trick! Thanks @satya164!!

Comment: Facing same issue. App Crashing with react-navigatoin.  But i dont have this lines "sourceExts": ["js","jsx","svg","ts","tsx"] in my app.json file, but its still crashing. Help Please